# Cannot access my NSArray with literal integer but works dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, exception, nsarray

I can't access to the NSArray data with literal integer, it throws me some exceptions, index bouds (0 , 0) but actually that's wrong, because if I loop it dynamically it works... My code:

```
        for (NSString *cada in barcos)
        {
            NSArray *datos = [cada componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
            NSString *consulta = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Barco (ID,Zona,Nombre,Matricula,Imagen) VALUES ('%d','%@',\"%@\",\"\",\"%@\");",contador,[datos objectAtIndex:0],[datos objectAtIndex:1],[datos objectAtIndex:2]];
            insert_stmt = (char *)[consulta UTF8String];
            sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            contador++;
        }
```

I tested this and works... but I don't want that:

```
        for (NSString *cada in barcos)
        {
            NSArray *datos = [cada componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
            for (int c = 0; c < [datos count]; c++)
                NSLog(@"%@",[datos objectAtIndex:c]);
            // It prints all very good, there is only 0 to 2 position always
        }
```

EDIT:

```
        for (NSString *cada in barcos)
        {
            NSArray *datos = [cada componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
            for (int c = 0; c < [datos count]; c++)
            {
                NSLog(@"posicion array %d - dato: %@",c,[datos objectAtIndex:c]);
            }// Here we are good, the loop is OK
            NSString *consulta = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Barco (ID,Zona,Nombre,Matricula,Imagen) VALUES ('%d','%@',\"%@\",\"\",\"%@\");",contador,[datos objectAtIndex:0],[datos objectAtIndex:1],[datos objectAtIndex:2]]; // Here crash, cannot go to objectAtIndex:1
            /*insert_stmt = (char *)[consulta UTF8String];
            sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);*/
            contador++;
        }
```

My array prints this:

```
2013-01-22 12:54:36.386 whales[4076:707] posicion array 0 - dato: Spirit of the seas
2013-01-22 12:54:36.403 whales[4076:707] posicion array 1 - dato: spirit_of_the_seas.bmp
2013-01-22 12:54:36.410 whales[4076:707] posicion array 2 - dato: 1
2013-01-22 12:54:36.419 whales[4076:707] posicion array 0 - dato: Nashira I
2013-01-22 12:54:36.425 whales[4076:707] posicion array 1 - dato: nashira1.bmp
2013-01-22 12:54:36.432 whales[4076:707] posicion array 2 - dato: 2
2013-01-22 12:54:36.441 whales[4076:707] posicion array 0 - dato: Tina Excursiones
2013-01-22 12:54:36.448 whales[4076:707] posicion array 1 - dato: tinaexcursiones.bmp
2013-01-22 12:54:36.454 whales[4076:707] posicion array 2 - dato: 3
2013-01-22 12:54:36.461 whales[4076:707] posicion array 0 - dato: Catlanza
2013-01-22 12:54:36.467 whales[4076:707] posicion array 1 - dato: catlanza.bmp
2013-01-22 12:54:36.473 whales[4076:707] posicion array 2 - dato: 3
2013-01-22 12:54:36.478 whales[4076:707] posicion array 0 - dato:
```

That's my for + NSLog so it's OK, but manually not

Comment: I did not get your problem :(

Comment: I cannot do this NSLog(@"%@",[datos objectAtIndex:1]); because it give an exception of index bounds... But I can do with a for and it does three times, so I have index from 0 to 2 (3 positions), and with a literal integer like 1 or 2 cannot (I can access with a 0).

Comment: you cannot do 2nd code snippet?

Comment: I cannot the first, but the second I can.

Comment: You can't do `NSLog(@"%@",[datos objectAtIndex:1]);` because, at the time you're doing it, there aren't at least two elements in the array.  (Keep in mind that element #1 is the second element, after #0.)

Comment: Similarly, `[datos objectAtIndex:0],[datos objectAtIndex:1],[datos objectAtIndex:2]` will only work if there are at least 3 elements in the array.  And you say above that there are at most 2.

Comment: My doubt is... [datos count] always return 3, then the for will loop from 0 to 2, and NSLog(@"%@",[datos objectAtIndex:c]); will print all perfectly with 0, 1 and 2... so why if I do manually will exception? I really don't understand, all languages can do it perfectly as far as I know.

Comment: Can you check by printing "cada" and "datos" in NSLog.

Comment: I know and I certify that always I'm gonna have 0 , 1 and 2 position in the array, but it cannot by accessible manually, only with a for loop by now and I don't know why... I Edit my post...

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. What you should do is to add an [exception breakpoint](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/060-Debug_Your_App/debug_app.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH3-SW18) and inspect both `datos` and `cada`

Comment: I edited my content, and I have an exception breakpoint and that's why I did not understand why it's that.

Comment: If the snippet you added is everything you get back from nslog, then the problem is the very last line. You have an array with just one element there.

Comment: mmh @Alladinian I realized that, but with SQLite code will not insert anything (I mean, it should insert data properly till the error), but yes I figured that, thanks =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fix is:

```
        for(int c = 0; c < ([barcos count] - 1); c++)
        {
            NSArray *datos = [[barcos objectAtIndex:c] componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];
            NSString *consulta = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Barco (ID,Zona,Nombre,Matricula,Imagen) VALUES ('%d','%@',\"%@\",\"\",\"%@\");",contador,[datos objectAtIndex:0],[datos objectAtIndex:1],[datos objectAtIndex:2]];
            insert_stmt = (char *)[consulta UTF8String];
            sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            contador++;
        }
```

so simple solution...

Answer (score 1):

Protect the access to the array with an if:

```
if( datos.count>=3)
{
    NSString *consulta = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Barco (ID,Zona,Nombre,Matricula,Imagen) VALUES ('%d','%@',\"%@\",\"\",\"%@\");",contador,[datos objectAtIndex:0],[datos objectAtIndex:1],[datos objectAtIndex:2]];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"datos count is %u",datos.count);
}
```

This will make you understand when the datos array hasn't 3 elements.